# The function onclick in html gets called only on the first click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a To do list, have done all things, but when I try to edit task, I am able to do it but when I try to edit the task again the function doesn't get called.

I tried to fix it and look for solutions online but they didn't help and I am a beginner only.
The to do list has the capability to edit, save and delete the tasks, but edit works only on the first time when the button is clicked.

```
const taskList = document.getElementById('task-list');
const taskInput = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]');

const addButton = document.getElementById('add-button');

window.onload = () =>{
  let savedTasks = localStorage.getItem('tasksList');
  taskList.innerHTML = savedTasks;
}

addButton.addEventListener('click' , ()=>{
    let title = taskInput.value;
    const taskElement = document.createElement('li');
    taskElement.classList.add('task');
      taskElement.innerHTML = `
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="window.checked()" class="checkBox">
        <span class = "title">${title}</span>
        <button class = "edit" onclick="edit()">Edit</button>
        <button class = "delete" onclick = "dlt()">Delete</button>
      `;
      taskList.appendChild(taskElement);
      taskInput.value = '';
      
      localStorage.setItem('tasksList', taskList.innerHTML);
});
    
const edit = ()=>{
  let parent = event.target.parentNode;

  let title = parent.querySelector('.title');
  title.contentEditable = true;
  title.focus();

  let editBtn = parent.querySelector('.edit');
  editBtn.innerText = 'Save';
  editBtn.addEventListener('click' , ()=>{
    title.contentEditable = false;
    editBtn.innerText = 'Edit';
    localStorage.setItem('tasksList', taskList.innerHTML);
  });

}

const dlt = ()=>{
  let parent = event.target.parentNode;
  parent.remove();
  localStorage.setItem('tasksList', taskList.innerHTML);
}

const checked = ()=>{
  let parent = event.target.parentNode;
  console.log(parent)
  let title = parent.querySelector('.title');
  if(parent.querySelector('.checkBox').checked){
    title.classList.add('checked');
  }
  if(!parent.querySelector('.checkBox').checked && title.classList.contains('checked')){
    title.classList.remove('checked');
  }

}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>To-Do List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <script src="app.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>To-Do List</h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Add new task">
      <button id="add-button">Add</button>
    <ul id="task-list">

    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should not be using global `event`

Comment: Your code runs before the html elements are on the page. Your variables `taskList, taskInput, addButton` are going to be null.

Comment: `editBtn.addEventListener` - this doesn't override the function you defined with onclick.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is

```js
editBtn.addEventListener('click' , ()=>{ ... })
```

unsets before setted "onclick="edit()""

The simplest way imho to repair this is set only one event to one element, in which you can divide it by "if" condition wh

```js
  if(title.contentEditable == 'false' || title.contentEditable == 'inherit' ){
    title.contentEditable = true;
    title.focus();
    editBtn.innerText = 'Save';
  } else {
    title.contentEditable = false;
    editBtn.innerText = 'Edit';
    localStorage.setItem('tasksList', taskList.innerHTML);
  }
```

because "inherit" is default value for "contentEditable", and "false" is when you want to edit

BTW - I commented localstorage because it throw error on stack overflow snippets

```js
const taskList = document.getElementById('task-list');
const taskInput = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]');

const addButton = document.getElementById('add-button');

window.onload = () =>{
  //let savedTasks = localStorage.getItem('tasksList');
  //taskList.innerHTML = savedTasks;
}

addButton.addEventListener('click' , ()=>{
    let title = taskInput.value;
    const taskElement = document.createElement('li');
    taskElement.classList.add('task');
      taskElement.innerHTML = `
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="window.checked()" class="checkBox">
        <span class = "title">${title}</span>
        <button class = "edit" onclick="edit()">Edit</button>
        <button class = "delete" onclick = "dlt()">Delete</button>
      `;
      taskList.appendChild(taskElement);
      taskInput.value = '';
      
      //localStorage.setItem('tasksList', taskList.innerHTML);
});
    
const edit = ()=>{
  let parent = event.target.parentNode;
  let title = parent.querySelector('.title');
  let editBtn = parent.querySelector('.edit');

  if(title.contentEditable == 'false' || title.contentEditable == 'inherit' ){
    title.contentEditable = true;
    title.focus();
    editBtn.innerText = 'Save';
  } else {
    title.contentEditable = false;
    editBtn.innerText = 'Edit';
    //localStorage.setItem('tasksList', taskList.innerHTML);
  }
}

const dlt = ()=>{
  let parent = event.target.parentNode;
  parent.remove();
  //localStorage.setItem('tasksList', taskList.innerHTML);
}

const checked = ()=>{
  let parent = event.target.parentNode;
  let title = parent.querySelector('.title');
  if(parent.querySelector('.checkBox').checked){
    title.classList.add('checked');
  }
  if(!parent.querySelector('.checkBox').checked && title.classList.contains('checked')){
    title.classList.remove('checked');
  }

}
```

```html
<h1>To-Do List</h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Add new task">
      <button id="add-button">Add</button>
    <ul id="task-list">

    </ul>
```

Comment: I meant in this specific case, but i used too general words. Thanks for pointing it out, I've corrected it.